# Loop for pagination params in requests.get

Tags: python, for-loop, pagination, request

I want to pars vacancies. And my goal is to pars vacancies just one company

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?employer_id=80').json() 
r
```

If I do so I get by default only 20 vacancies (0 page) though there are 488

```
'found': 488
```

and

```
'page': 0,
'pages': 25,
'per_page': 20
```

I can make loop

```
vac = []
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0, 25)):
    vac.append(requests.get("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?employer_id=80", params={'page': i}).json())
```

But I get just 25 vacancies (one for every page). 
Or I can do

```
vac = []
for j in tqdm_notebook(range(0, 20)):
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0, 500)):
        vac.append(requests.get("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?employer_id=80", params={'page': i, 'per_page': j}).json())
```

But this is a very expensive way, we repeat a lot of actions. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manually set the page and per_page parameters, per the API's [documentation](https://github.com/hhru/api/blob/master/docs/general.md). However, you don't need a loop for the per_page parameter - it should be a static number (20):

```
vac = []
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0, 25)):
    vac.append(requests.get("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?employer_id=80", params={'page': i, 'per_page':20}).json())
```

Also, consider making the range of pages to iterate dynamic based on the first page of pagination results.